# How to set the width of a component(HBOX) dynamically in flex

Tags: apache-flex, size, flex2

I have a custom component that is extending the HBOX. Am adding a VBOX and a "HBOX" to it as its children.The VBOX has a label which acts as title to component and adding/deleting a pair of LINK  BUTTONS to the "HBOX" dynamically on a particular event(might be a button click).

The parent HBOX width must grow/shrink whenever the link button is added/deleted dynamically.
How to calculate the same.I do not know.

Comment: Try with percentHeight/percentWidth function, please see the example in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set width and height dinamically with this:

```
var hb:HBox;

hb.percentHeight = 100; //height:100%
hb.percentWidth = 100; //widht:100%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set width with percent (100%) or bind width property to another width property (in mxml with {}).